# Chrome wont progressively render this page with script tag at end of body

Tags: javascript, html, performance, google-chrome

Steve Souders' [Rule 6 - Put Scripts at the Bottom](http://stevesouders.com/hpws/js-bottom.php) doesn't seem to work on Chrome 32. I get a blank page for 10 seconds. Weirdly it does work in the [side-by-side (iframe) comparison](http://stevesouders.com/hpws/move-scripts.php). Any idea why? I thought one of the advantages to putting scripts at the end of the body was to enable progressive rendering?

It works fine in Firefox 27 and Safari 7.

Update: actually it does work the first time you load the page, or if you open a new tab and paste the URL, but not when you refresh the page.

Update: ok even weirder, it works if I refresh during the 10 second wait i.e. hit refresh and then 2 seconds in I hit refresh again. But if I wait the full 10 seconds for the page to render and then hit refresh, I get nothing for another 10 seconds.

Update: hmmm, I've just noticed that if I open Chrome dev tools during the 10s wait, it suddenly displays the page!

Can other people reproduce this?

Comment: Do you have a link to the specific code you're having trouble with?

Comment: The rendering delay is probably due to the CSS being fetched again.

Comment: @jfriend00 there are links in the question to live demos

Comment: @FabrícioMatté all the styles are inline

Comment: Can you provide a link for us to test? It will be easier to diagnose possible issues then.

Comment: the script urls change every few seconds, so a refresh before they change will pull cached copies. not a very good demo on steve's part...